# How to tell all NSDocument instances to refresh

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsdocument

I'm just starting to experiment with a very simple macOS document-based Swift application. The `NSDocument` -> `NSViewController` has an `NSTextField` label and I have a separate preference window that is loaded from the menu - it simply has a colour picker on it.

What I want to be able to do is select a colour in the preferences and then notify all `NSDocument` instances that they have to refresh to pick up this new colour.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post a `Notification`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - this works :)